# swift array method "starts(with:)" causing value of type "Range<Int>" has no number "starts"

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm learning functions in swift's array and have encountered the following problem.

[image]

I copied the code directly from swift's API so didn't expect to have any problem. Can someone please tell me why is it giving out error message when typed in playground?

Comment: Swift 2 or Swift 3?

Comment: i believe the API i'm looking at is for swift 3

Comment: Are you in Xcode 8?

Comment: You need Xcode 8 for Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using Swift 2.2 and the syntax you're using is for Swift 3. Try:

```
print(a.startsWith(b))
```

Comment: Best way to figure these out is to start typing `a.star` and see what Xcode autocomplete offers.